# Retrieve value between two string using sed or awk

Tags: string, awk, sed, collect

I am trying to retrieve value between two strings which are present multiple time in one single line.

here is what I got:

```
time="1441491171" <DISP>something</DISP><DISP>stuff</DISP><DISP>possible</DISP>
```

the order for these strings as it might change by having additional strings...

I am trying to get these values are below:

```
"1441491171" something stuff possible
```

Many thanks for you help,
AL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's/time=//;s/<\/*DISP>/ /g'
```

These are two commands, separated by a semicolon:

- `s/time=//` removes the `time=` prefix
- `s/<\/*DISP>/ /g` removes the `<DISP>` or `</DISP>` tags by a space

Answer (score 0):

A different aproach selecting matches instead of deleting not wanted strings:

```
$ grep -oP 'time=\K"\d+"|(?<=DISP>)\w+(?=</DISP)' file
"1441491171" 
something
stuff
possible

$ grep -oP 'time=\K"\d+"|(?<=DISP>)\w+(?=</DISP)' file |tr  '\n' ' '
"1441491171"  something stuff possible
```